# MySQL InnoDB Global Var?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, innodb

I want to execute this code:
The idea is to get the item with the lowest `MID` that has not been used (`mutex = 0`). To prevent other Threads of reading this line `FOR UPDATE` is used and `UPDATE` decreases `mutex`.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT MID as m, sender, receiver, content FROM queue WHERE mutex = 0 ORDER BY MID ASC limit 1 FOR UPDATE; 
UPDATE queue set mutex = -1 WHERE MID = m;
COMMIT;
```

However `m` is only known when the `SELECT` line is executed. How do I access it in the next query, without breaking the query, which would stop the `TRANSACTION` ?

P.S.: I know that mutex is something else than the thing I am using it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @m:=MID, sender, receiver, content FROM queue WHERE mutex = 0 ORDER BY MID ASC limit 1 FOR UPDATE; 
UPDATE queue set mutex = -1 WHERE MID = @m;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know mysql supports this.